# Fastboot problems on AMD Ryzen laptop - USB 3 issue

Tags: usb, android, adb

I'm trying to run fastboot commands from my HP Envy x360 15z Ryzen laptop.

Fastboot commands are unreliable. The same command performs inconsistently. Whereas they work without an issue on my i7 6th Gen CPU.

I've tried on both Linux (Manjaro, Antergos) and Windows 10.

Could this be a USB issue on my laptop? How do I fix this?

```
bash> fastboot boot twrp-3.2.3-0-whyred.img 
Downloading 'boot.img'
FAILED (command write failed (Success))
Finished. Total time: 0.023s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a USB 3.0 issue. I tried it on a newer Intel laptop with a 9th gen CPU with only USB 3.0 ports. The issue was still present. After a lot of Googling, on XDA asked me try it using a USB 2.0 HUB. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a xiaomi mi a2 I had the almost same issue. I was doing things on fastboot flawlessly on my i7 6500u laptop. But after I switched to ryzen 5 2600x, my jasmine doesn't accept any fastboot commands after the first one. (It doesn't even do the job if I flash a big partition) After flashing, I usually get "press any key to reboot" print on my phone's display.